# Where does downloaded files stored in android

Tags: android

Where does downloaded files stored in android when there is no memory card and how to access it from my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored in device's internal storage, if you haven't chosen to store it in the sd-card. Internal storage make use of linux file system permissions, so files will private to your application and other applications cannot access them.

If you are talking about media files, you can make them accessible everywhere by adding them in their respective content providers.

To open a file use `openFileOutput()` which return a file stream.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the article on [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) which also provides a code example for accessing the external storage.